# How to filter the Kajona News backend list

Tags: php, content-management-system

I just wondered what's the best way to set up a fixed filter-criteria for the backend list of Kajonas news module.
I'm able to set a title-filter using the backend, but I want the filter to be set up for every user, so even before something is entered into the filter-form. It's ok to me if this is just the initial filter-value, so the user is allowed to change the value afterwards.